# CORS Policy Error When using AutoSuggest API

Tags: cors, bing-maps, bing

I had been using the AutoSuggest UI from past 2months and i was not receiving any error. today it was giving me CORS policy error on typing on the input box. I had also tested the sample code from the bing development sdk(https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/autosuggestui) and checked in the localhost it is still the same error where previously i did use the same code when building. Below is the error log for your references.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.bing.com/api/v6/Places/AutoSuggest?q=dallas&appid=************&mv8cid=*****************&mv8ig=***&localMapView=***,**,**,***&localcircularview=1***,100&count=4&structuredaddress=true&types=place,address&setmkt=en-IN&setlang=en-IN&histcnt=&favcnt=&clientid=**' from origin 'https://localhost:**' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Thanks,

Prajwal

Comment: I am having the same issue today. It seems like a problem with the sdk itself.

Comment: We are also having the same issue.  We're attempting to whitelist our domains in the Bing dev dashboard to see if that fixes things.

Comment: It is working today. Can anyone let know why this happened?

Comment: The problem seems to be resolved.